# pod spec lint - Getting xcodebuild notes

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, podspec

When I `lint` a pod of mine

```
$ pod spec lint
```

I'm getting some notes of this type

> - NOTE  | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  MyPod/MyClass.m:68:40: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
>   ...

Is there a way to get them from xcode (I can't find those) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the `GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION` warning in Xcode. You should be able to search for some of this string to find it.

Comment: Ok thx. The question was more about how to get these errors from xcode instead of from `pod spec lint`

Comment: Yep. You just need to set that flag in your build settings in Xcode?

Comment: Ha ok I'll check that